# Need help with this question concerning compact spaces

Tags: calculus, general-topology, analysis, compactness

Let the set be given like in the following manner:
$$\{x_n: n\in\mathbb N\}\subset \mathbb{R^n}$$
$$l^2=\left\{\{x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\,\Big|\, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|^2<\infty\right\}.$$

Prove that there exist closed and bounded sets, such that are not compact. (notebook answer)
\begin{align}
E&=\{e_n\mid n \in \mathbb{N}\} \\ e_1&=(1,0,0,\ldots,0,\ldots) \\ e_2&=(0,1,0,...,0,...) \\ &\;\;\vdots \\ e_n&=(0,0,0,\ldots,1,\ldots) 
\end{align}
with $\|e_n \|=1, n \in \mathbb{N}$.

This set is bounded , because it is always on a unit sphere , ***but this sequence isn't compact because the members are always on a fixed distance***:$$\|e_n-e_m\|=\begin{cases}0,& n=m \\{} \\  \sqrt{2},& n\neq m \end{cases}$$

What is the reasoning behind this predication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider an open cover of $E$ consisting of balls of radius, say, 1.3, centered at the points $e_n$, i.e. $\{B(e_n, 1.3) : n = 1, 2,\dots\}$.  Does it have a finite subcover?  (For that matter, does it have any proper subcover?)

Comment: Understood. How is this set closed if there are an infinite number of fixed points?

Comment: @BozoVulicevic: What definition of "closed" do you want to use?  (By the way, "fixed point" is not the word you are looking for here.)

Comment: That the complement is open for example? That might be a tough one to follow?

Comment: You can also look at the theorem that in every metric space, every compact set is closed.

Comment: @BozoVulicevic: Pick an arbitrary point $x \in E^c$; we will show it is an interior point of $E^c$.  Consider the open ball $B$ about $x$ of radius $\sqrt{2}/2$.  Use the triangle inequality to show that $B$ cannot contain two or more points of $E$.  If $B$ contains no points of $E$, then $B \subset E^c$, meaning that $x$ is an interior point of $E^c$ and we are done.  Otherwise $B$ contains exactly one point of $E$; call it $y$.  Let $r = \|x-y\|$ which is a positive number.  Consider the open ball around $x$ of radius $r$; it contains no points of $E$, so we conclude as before.